# Error while load genymotion in debian jessie

Tags: debian, shared-libraries

i got this error:
./genymotion: error while loading shared libraries: libQtScript.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to run a binary that is dynamically linked against a library that is not present on your system.

Install the library package that provides the missing library:

```
 apt-file search libQtScript.so.4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using debian jessie you should install this:

```
apt-get install libqtwebkit4 libqt4-script libqt4-svg libqt4-sql
```

Here we have a full tutorial:
http://tukitanotes.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/genymotion-on-debian-jessie.html